# Upload image first then save/submit

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have a form with several text inputs and an image input. The image input, once selected, needs to be uploaded (via an "Upload" button beside it) first to give user an opportunity to crop their uploaded image, before the form can be saved/submitted.

I want to know How I should implement the "upload first then save" design? Note I am using jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I find it often simple to upload via a own popup window. That way the upload has its own form.

I have also used a UpdatePanel to async-upload the image.

Comment: But the question is, or seems to be: *how should he implement this design?*